# How to cast away constness on a function pointer?

Tags: c++, casting, clang

The following code compiles clean on GCC but gets an error on Clang:

```
typedef void (MyFuncPtr)();
void foo(const MyFuncPtr* ptr)
{   
    MyFuncPtr* myTestPtr = ptr;
}
```

Clang error:

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'MyFuncPtr *' (aka 'void (*)()') with an lvalue of type 'const MyFuncPtr *'
  (aka 'void (const *)()')
```

I have tried the following solutions and they all get errors except for the C-style cast:

const_cast:

```
MyFuncPtr* myTestPtr = const_cast<MyFuncPtr*>(ptr);
```

Error:

```
error: const_cast to 'MyFuncPtr *' (aka 'void (*)()'), which is not a reference, pointer-to-object, or pointer-to-data-member
```

reintepret_cast:

```
MyFuncPtr* myTestPtr = reinterpret_cast<MyFuncPtr*>(ptr);
```

Error:

```
error: reinterpret_cast from 'const MyFuncPtr *' (aka 'void (const *)()') to 'MyFuncPtr *' (aka 'void (*)()') casts away
  qualifiers
```

C-style cast:

```
MyFuncPtr* myTestPtr = (MyFuncPtr*) ptr;
```

Success!

Questions:
Why doesn't const_cast work on function pointers?
Is using a C-style cast the only solution?
Why does this work on GCC with no casting?

Thanks in advance!

COMPILER VERSIONS:
*G++ version 4.6.3
*clang version 3.5.0.210790

Comment: The type `const MyFuncPtr*` is almost nonsense and just as useless (as in almost completely useless).  And every use I can think of doesn't have an *instance* associated with it.  Why do you have this type in your program?  Overly generic code?

Comment: note that `MyFuncPtr` is actually a function type, not a function pointer type (But this doesn't invalidate your question, actually it makes it more interesting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `MyFuncPtr` is a function type (not a function pointer type). Your code tries to use the type `const MyFuncPtr`, which is applying `const` to a function type.

However, according to the note in C++14 [dcl.fct]/6, there is no such thing as a const-qualified function type:

> The effect of a *cv-qualifier-seq* in a function declarator is not the same as adding cv-qualification on top of the function type. In the latter case, the cv-qualifiers are ignored.  [Note: a function type that has a *cv-qualifier-seq* is not a cv-qualified type; there are no cv-qualified function types. —*end note* ]

This section is primarily talking about *cv-qualifier-seq*, which is the qualifiers that occur after a member function. However, in passing, it seems to specify that cv-qualifiers applied to a function type in general are ignored.

So your code ought to be the same as:

```
typedef void (MyFuncPtr)();
void foo(MyFuncPtr* ptr)
{   
    MyFuncPtr* myTestPtr = ptr;
}
```

which would mean clang is bugged to report an error.

Comment: I am using c++11 in this instance, does that effect your answer?

Comment: On clang version 3.7 I start to get the following warning which matches the answer above: 3: <source>:3:10: warning: 'const' qualifier on function type 'MyFuncPtr' (aka 'void ()') has no effect [-Wignored-qualifiers]
void foo(const MyFuncPtr* ptr)

Comment: @Chadness3 OK, sounds like clang already found the bug in 3.5 and fixed it for 3.7